# Java Input and Out put

Tags: java

Hi my code should do this instruction below but am not getting it at all

**The user can enter as many positive floating-point numbers on the console as desired. Zero (or a
negative numbers) signals end of input (no more numbers can be entered). After input the program
displays
 the smallest number entered (min)
 the largest number entered (max)
 the mean of all numbers entered (mean)
Do NOT use arrays for this assignment, even if you know them.**

Sample should look like this

> enter numbers: \n
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 0  \n
>   numbers entered: 6 \n
>   minimum: 1.00 \n
>   maximum:6.00 \n
>   mean: 3.50\n
>
> enter numbers: \n
>   0 \n
>   no number entered.

```
public class LoopStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double max, min, sum=0, input, mean=0;
    int counter = 0;

    TextIO.putln("enter numbers:");

    do
    {
        input = TextIO.getDouble();

        min = input;
        max = input;

        counter++;

        if (input > max)
            max = input;

        if ( input < min)
            min = input;

        sum = sum + input;



        } while( input != 0);
    mean = sum / counter;
    TextIO.putf("numbers entered:%d\n", counter);
    TextIO.putf("minimum:%f\n", min);
    TextIO.putf("maximum:%f\n", max);
    TextIO.putf("mean:%f", mean);





}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign your `max` and `min` before you test whether they are greater/less than the current `max`/`min`:

```
min = input;
max = input;
```

This means that they both equal whatever the person entered last.

Tidying up your code and removing those calls yields:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double max = 0;
    double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    double sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        final double d = scanner.nextDouble();
        if (d <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        sum += d;
        max = Math.max(max, d);
        min = Math.min(min, d);
        ++counter;
    }
    System.out.println("Max=" + max);
    System.out.println("Min=" + min);
    System.out.println("Ave=" + sum / counter);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for too many question but what does the Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; do ?

Comment: @Michael what do you think it does? Have you heard of this google thing? you could look up the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY).

Comment: I am a newbie to programming. I looked it up on google before i asked you and the explanations I read through where not clear at all. It did resolve the max and minimum issue but i dont understand how it worked