# Incorporating min and max value checker in my while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to incorporate the ability to get a min a max value from the users input, but can't seem to get it working. I tried an while loop, but not sure how to really store the min and max value.

```
public class examReview
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfInputs=0;
        int currentMax
        int currentMin=0;
        double sum=0;
        int intInput = 1;
        int num;

        while (intInput != 0)
        {
            intInput = input.nextInt();

            currentMin = intInput;
            currentMax = intInput;
            System.out.println("currentminis" + currentMin);
            System.out.println("currentmaxis" + currentMax);

            sum += intInput;
            numOfInputs++;
        }

        System.out.println(numOfInputs - 1);     //Prints number of input
        System.out.println(sum);                 //Prints sum of all values entered
        System.out.println(sum/(numOfInputs-1)); //Prints average
        System.out.println(currentMin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question partly what to make int currentMax? Is that why you left off a semicolon? BTW there's no such thing as an "if loop"

Comment: I don't really know whether you were talking about an if-statement or a while-loop. I assumed the latter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Input and Out put](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934475/java-input-and-out-put)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently change the `currentMin` and `currentMax` each time round the while loop.

Clearly these need setting outside the loop.

```
   int currentMax=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
   int currentMin=Interger.MAX_VALUE;
```

and adjusting as required inside the while loop

```
    while (intInput != 0)
    {
        intInput = input.nextInt();

        if(intInput<currentMin) currentMin = intInput;
        if(intInput>currentMax) currentMax = intInput;
        System.out.println("currentminis" + currentMin);
        System.out.println("currentmaxis" + currentMax);

        sum += intInput;
        numOfInputs++;
    }
```

Comment: You can use zero for `currentMax` as that is the absolute minimum in this case. You can also use `Math.max` and `Math.min` to tidy the code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why is the absolute minimum zero?

Comment: Because of `intInput != 0` (which I suppose should be `intInput > 0`).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Will the scanner not allow a nextInt of -1?

Comment: I saw a very similar question and there the OP said any number greater than 0 rather any any number that isn't zero - I assumed this OP has the same problem. Upon reading the question that isn't stated anywhere however - my mistake.

Comment: Helped a lot, I threw in an && != 0 in the if statement of intInput < currentMin as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (intInput != 0)
  {
     intInput = input.nextInt();

     if(numOfInputs==0 || intInput<currentMin)currentMin = intInput;
     if(numOfInputs==0 || intInput>currentMax)currentMax = intInput;
     System.out.println("currentminis" + currentMin);
     System.out.println("currentmaxis" + currentMax);

     sum += intInput;
     numOfInputs++;

  }
```

Comment: What does `flag` do? `1` is not calculated into a boolean 'true' in Java.

Comment: @maksimov  flag was dumb...now its gone.

Comment: This is somewhat inelegant, take a look at my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934505/2071828).

Answer (score 0):

Tom has the right answer, you want to test your current{Min,Max} against intInput:

```
if (intInput < currentMin ) {
      currentMin = intInput;
}
```

You can simplify the flag log by assigning currentMin and currentMax to outlier values and as long as you get at least one input, which would already lead to a problem since your average would be a divide by zero, you should be OK.

```
int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int currentMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

This way any value will be greater than the currentMax and less than the currentMin and you can get rid of the flag.

Also note that average should probably be `sum / numOfInputs` rather than `sum / numOfInputs-1`.

Comment: It's minus 1 because number of inputs is counting the final 0 being entered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've written too much code. You should use the java API:

- Use a `List<Integer>` to hold all your input
- Use [`list.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29) to automatically keep track of the quantity of numbers
- Use [`Collections.min(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29) and [`Collections.max(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) to find the min/max

Try this:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = input.nextInt(); i > 0; i = input.nextInt()) {
        sum += i;
        list.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println(list.size());          //Prints number of input
    System.out.println(sum);                  //Prints sum of all values entered
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty() ? 0d ; sum/list.size()); //Prints average
    System.out.println(Collections.min(list));//Prints min
    System.out.println(Collections.max(list));//Prints max
}
```

Comment: That would be the way to do it, but I suspect "Do NOT use arrays for this assignment, even if you know them." is also true for this question as they are [very similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934475/java-input-and-out-put).

Comment: @BoristheSpider A `List` is not an array :)

Comment: While theoretically the size of the input is indefinite this may be a dangerous approach.

Comment: @maksimov dangerous? Why?

Comment: Input may be infinite, the list isn't.

Comment: @maksimov lists are effectively infinite. Considering input is from the keyboard, and assuming one number entered per second by the user and assuming a modest 1Gb of JVM for the list elements (which take 4 bytes each), it would take approximately 10 years of continuous input 24/7 to fill memory. I think it is reasonable to say that this code is safe.

Comment: I assume there's more than one way to send input via the stardard in :-p

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your max to smallest value, and your min to biggest. Then compare and set when needed:

```
int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int currentMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

while(haveInput) {
   if (intInput > currentMax) currentMax = intInput;
   if (intInput < currentMin) currentMin = intInput;
   // get more input
}
```